# Need to cycle through a sequence of mysql query results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to continuously cycle through 14 query results from a MySQL table for a Kiosk

Display each result for 10 seconds

Any examples would be appreciated either in PHP or JS

Right now I have 14 php files that I cycle through with this meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10; url=ccml2.php\" the page changes on each to goto the next page, the last points to the first.
But I am thinking that there has to be a way to do this with a single php file.
Each query changes the where on select to get the values needed to display.
e.g. select field1, field2 from table where field3 = value.
Do query, display results for 10 seconds, change to next value, repeat.
value can be 1 to 14

Here is first attempt but it does not do what I think it should do

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
$query = sprintf("SELECT ClassName, ClassId FROM class");
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $ICName[]=$row['ClassName'];  //gets 14 Class Names
  $IC_Id[] = $row['ClassId']; // gets matching ID 1 to 14
  }
for($x=0;$x<$result->num_rows;$x++)
  {
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<Title>Cactus Combat Match League</Title>";
    echo "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"ccml.css\" media=\"all\" />";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<img width=\"1280\" height=\"190\" src=\"images/Banner.png\"></img>";
    echo "<p></p>";
    echo "<p></p>";
    echo "<h2>Thursday Night Match Scores 11/14/2013</h2>";
    echo "<table border=\"1\" width=\"1200\" align=\"center\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class=\"th1\" colspan = \"8\">".$ICName[$x]."</th>"; // Display Class Name
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">#</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">Name</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">Stage 1</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">Stage 2</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">Stage 3</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">Stage 4</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">Stage 5</th>";
    echo "<th class=\"th2\">TOTAL</th>";
    echo "</tr>";  // following gets results for this Class
    $query1 = sprintf("SELECT mid, SName, Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4, Stage5, Total FROM shooter WHERE cid=".$IC_Id[$x]." AND mdate='2013-11-14' ORDER BY Total");
    $result1 = $mysqli->query($query1) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) // Display Results
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td class=\"t1\">".$row1['mid']."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t3\">".$row1['SName']."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t2\">".number_format((float)$row1['Stage1'], 2, '.', '')."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t2\">".number_format((float)$row1['Stage2'], 2, '.', '')."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t2\">".number_format((float)$row1['Stage3'], 2, '.', '')."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t2\">".number_format((float)$row1['Stage4'], 2, '.', '')."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t2\">".number_format((float)$row1['Stage5'], 2, '.', '')."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"t4\">".number_format((float)$row1['Total'], 2, '.', '')."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo"</html>";
    sleep(1);
  }
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Give us more details please..

Comment: sharing your existing code will be helpful

Comment: How do I answer the two who responded?

Comment: Right now I have 14 php files that I cycle through with this <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10; url=ccml2.php\"> the page changes on each to goto the next page, the last points to the first. But I am thinking that there has to be a way to do this with a single php file. Each query changes the where on select to get the values needed to display. e.g. select field1, field2 from table where field3 = value.  Do query, display results for 10 seconds, change to next value, repeat. value can be 1 to 14.

Comment: Hope this helps get it off hold

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a slightly more elegant solution.

Problem: Sequence display results from Shooting match (Consists of 25 class's of results), followed by the number of shooters displayed in order of time for the match, followed by each stage of the match top three shooters. Results stored in MySQL database).

Each result is filter by the date of the match.

Initialize a table with the start of each class, standing, part of standing, stage and date of match

First display each class for 5 seconds if there are shooters in that class, or 1 second if none.
Then Display the standings of the shooters 12 at a time till done.
Then Display top three shooters for each stage.

I will just show code for the first (Show the results for each class of shooter)

There probably is a more elegant way to do this, but this works.
The other two are much the same just the data and table  differ.
Start of code

```
// What Class to Deal with and What Match Date to Display
$query = sprintf("SELECT class_cnt, thur FROM CCnt");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
      $Class_Id = $row[0];              // Set the Class ID from the database
      $rdate=row[1];            // Set the Date of the Match to Display
      }
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Format Display Date in M-D-Y format
$pieces = explode("-", $rdate);
$ddate = $pieces[1]."/".$pieces[2]."/".$pieces[0];

// Get the Name of the Class
$query = sprintf("SELECT ClassName FROM class WHERE ClassId=%d", $Class_Id);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
      {
      $ICName = $row[0];
      }
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Select Data to Display
$query = sprintf("SELECT mdate, cid, mid, SName, Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, Stage4, Stage5, Total FROM shooter WHERE cid=%d AND mdate='%s' ORDER BY Total", $Class_Id, $rdate);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
// Adjust refresh time based on if there are Results
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_cnt > 0)
    $dtime = 5;    // 5 deconds if results
else
    $dtime = 1;    // 1 second if none

// Start of HTML Output
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>";
echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">";
echo "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">";
echo "<head>";
printf("<Title>Cactus Combat %s Results</Title>", $ICName );                           // Title the page
echo "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"ccml.css\" media=\"all\" />";  // Get Style file
// Check to see what Class to display
switch ($Class_Id)
  {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8:
  case 9:
  case 10:
  case 11:
  case 12:
  case 13:
  case 14:
  case 15:
  case 16:
  case 17:
  case 18:
  case 19:
  case 20:
  case 21:
  case 22:
  case 23:
  case 24:
  printf("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"%d; url=ccml1.php\">", $dtime);       // Class ID = 1 - 24 Refresh to same page
  break;
  case 25:
  printf("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"%d; url=ccml2.php\">", $dtime);       // Class ID = 25 Set to Next Page
  break;
  }
$Class_Id++;                                 // Increment the Class ID
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<img width=\"1280\" height=\"190\" src=\"images/Banner.png\"></img>";            // Display the Banner
echo "<p></p>";
echo "<p></p>";
echo "<h2>Thursday Night Match Scores ".$ddate."</h2>";// Display the Date of the Match
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class=\"th1\" colspan = \"8\">".$ICName."</th>";                             // Display Which Class these Results are
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";                                                                           // Output Table Headers
echo "<th class=\"th2\">#</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th3\">Name</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th4\">Stage 1</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th4\">Stage 2</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th4\">Stage 3</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th4\">Stage 4</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th4\">Stage 5</th>";
echo "<th class=\"th4\">TOTAL</th>";
echo "</tr>";

// Put Data into HTML Table Rows
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";                                                                         // Output Data Row
  printf("<td class=\"t1\">&nbsp;%d</td>",$row[2]);                //Match ID
  printf("<td class=\"t3\">&nbsp;%s</td>",$row[3]);                // Name
  printf("<td class=\"t2\"> %6.2f &nbsp;</td>",$row[4]);           //Stage 1 Time
  printf("<td class=\"t2\"> %6.2f &nbsp;</td>",$row[5]);           //Stage 2 Time
  printf("<td class=\"t2\"> %6.2f &nbsp;</td>",$row[6]);           //Stage 3 Time
  printf("<td class=\"t2\"> %6.2f &nbsp;</td>",$row[7]);           //Stage 4 Time
  printf("<td class=\"t2\"> %6.2f &nbsp;</td>",$row[8]);           //Stage 5 Time
  printf("<td class=\"t4\"> %6.2f &nbsp;</td>",$row[9]);           //Stage Total Time
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</body>";
echo"</html>";
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Update Class to Display in database
if ($Class_Id > 25)     // Check to see if we are done IF Yes reset the Class ID
  $Class_Id = 1;
$UpdQuery = sprintf("UPDATE CCnt SET class_cnt = %d", $Class_Id);// Update Class ID
mysqli_query($link, $UpdQuery);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```